# 'using' statement - if and where to place inside a parallel loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, thread-safety, using-statement

Looking for the most efficient and thread-safe way to perform the following:

I need to run over multiple remote servers in parallel, checking their IIS settings (I will only be reading data, not writing).
 Connection is made via the `ServerManager.OpenRemote()` call ([ServerManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) implements IDisposable).
For each remote server, I will be calling several different methods.

Is there a general best practice for handling IDisposible objects inside parallel loops?
Or would my specific case require a different implementation?

Below are couple of options I had in mind.

Appreciate the guidance!

**1. 'using' statement within the loop, and pass the IDisposible object to the "internal" methods**

```
void GeneralMethod(List<String> servers)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(servers, (server) =>
    {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(server))
        {
                DoSomething1(serverManager);
                DoSomething2(serverManager);
                DoSomething3(serverManager);
        }
    });
}

private static void DoSomething1(ServerManager serverManager)
{
    //Do stuff  
}
```

**2. Create the IDisposible object inside each "internal" method**

```
static void GeneralMethod2(List<String> servers)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(servers, (server) =>
    {
            DoSomething1(server);
            DoSomething2(server);
            DoSomething3(server);
    });
}

private static void DoSomething1(string server)
{
   using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(server))
   {
       //Do stuff
   }    
}
```

Comment: tbh, I'd do it at the level where it's needed. If it's not needed at the higher level, do it at a lower level.If you come across performance issues in doing it at the low level, do it at the higher level.

Comment: I don't see how `Parallel.ForEach()` relates to this question at all. You could be dealing with just a single server and no call to `Parallel.ForEach()` and still have the exact same question. In any case, at best there are too many unknowns to provide a good answer, and at worst it comes down strictly to a matter of preference (i.e. "primarily opinion-based").